# ExecuteReader in to XML in VB.net

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net, web-services, web

Created a Web Service in Vb.net which reads records from the Database. Trying to convert the selected record that is read using `ExecuteReader` in to XML.

```vb
<WebMethod()>
Public Function GetRoles(ByVal ID As String)
    ..........

    With sqlcmd2
        .Connection = sqlconn2
        .CommandText = sqlquery2
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID)
    End With
    sqlcmd2.CommandText = sqlquery2
    Dim officers As New XElement("GetAnOfficerRoles")
    Dim sqlreader2 = sqlcmd2.ExecuteReader()
    If sqlreader2 IsNot Nothing And sqlreader2.HasRows Then
        While sqlreader2.Read()
            Dim officer As New XElement("Officer")
            officers.Add(officer)
            officer.Add(New XElement("ID_LOGIN",sqlreader2("ID").ToString))
            officer.Add(New XElement("USER", sqlreader2("ID_USER").ToString))
            officer.Add(New XElement("ROLES", sqlreader2("ROLES").ToString))
        End While
    End If
    Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings
    settings.Indent = True
    Dim mStream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(mStream, settings)
    officers.WriteTo(writer)
    writer.Flush()
    mStream.Position = 0
    Dim sReader As New StreamReader(mStream)
    Dim response As String = sReader.ReadToEnd()
    Return response
```

The response I get is all in single statement..

```xml
<anyType d1p1:type="q1:string"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetAnOfficerRoles><Officer><ID>abcde</ID><USER>2</USER><ROLES> 1, 5, 9</ROLES></Officer></GetAnOfficerRoles></anyType>
```

WHAT I NEED IS XML

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetAnOfficerRolesResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <GetAnOfficerRoles>
         <Officer>
            <ID>abcded</ID>
            <USER>2</USER>
            <ROLES> 1, 5, 9</ROLES>
         </Officer>
    </GetAnOfficerRoles>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

What I see for other projects, they have used a **class and XMLSerializer(getType(ClassName))**

```vb
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0"),  _
 System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=true),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=false)>  _
Partial Public Class ClassName
```

Comment: `<soap:Envelope>` etc is the standard way for an asmx web service to wrap the response into. It is what you get by default if you use the service properly in the first place. You should not attempt to generate that envelope by yourself. In order to get the SOAP response you are showing, your web method must be declared as `Public Function GetRoles(ByVal ID As String) As GetAnOfficerRoles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xml linq to create an element :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.IO
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim xml As String =
            "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" + _
            "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" + _
                "<soap:Body>" + _
                    "<GetAnOfficerRolesResponse xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">" + _
                        "<GetAnOfficerRoles>" + _
                        "</GetAnOfficerRoles>" + _
                    "</GetAnOfficerRolesResponse>" + _
                "</soap:Body>" + _
            "</soap:Envelope>"


        Dim Envelope As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)

        Dim GetAnOfficerRoles As XElement = Envelope.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "GetAnOfficerRoles").FirstOrDefault()
        Dim ns As XNamespace = GetAnOfficerRoles.GetDefaultNamespace()

        While sqlreader2.Read()
            Dim officer As New XElement(ns + "Officer")
            GetAnOfficerRoles.Add(officer)

            officer.Add(New XElement(ns + "ID", sqlreader2("ID").ToString())
            officer.Add(New XElement(ns + "USERS", sqlreader2("USERS").ToString())
            officer.Add(New XElement(ns + "ROLES", sqlreader2("ROLES").ToString())
        End While


        Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings
        settings.Indent = True
        Dim mStream As New MemoryStream()
        Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(mStream, settings)
        Envelope.WriteTo(writer)
        writer.Flush()
        mStream.Position = 0
        Dim sReader As New StreamReader(mStream)
        Dim response As String = sReader.ReadToEnd()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. anyways, the result received is of typr = <anyType d1p1:type="q1:string"> and all XML are in one line.

Comment: To format try :         Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings
        settings.Indent = True
        Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(officers.ToString(), settings)
        writer.ToString()

Comment: Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(officers.ToString, settings) says illegal character on path.. on changing to (officers,setting) it says, "{"Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\prisms-po-12 1, 5, 9' is denied."}"

Comment: I tired to amend the changes you asked for. . Is it correct??

Comment: Try this instead :         Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings
        settings.Indent = True
        Dim mStream As New MemoryStream()
        Dim writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(mStream, settings)
        officers.WriteTo(writer)
        writer.Flush()
        mStream.Position = 0
        Dim output As String = mStream.ToString()

Comment: Sorry but get this as a result.<anyType d1p1:type="q1:string">System.IO.MemoryStream</anyType>

Comment: I think I got it correct this time.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help. I managed to retrieve XML results as per the requirements. .However the requirement is still not completed fully.I have made certain changes in my code above. .I am sorry to bother you as I am new to this web services in VB.net

Comment: Make sure you add the ns to following : officer.Add(New XElement(ns + "ID", sqlreader2("ID").ToString())

Comment: Thank you jdweng but the output is still the same all in one statement... I tried to using XmlHelper class and even after setting this  .NewLineOnAttributes = True, i cannot see the required result. anyways your help is highly appreciated. .Thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218743/discussion-between-marc-indra-and-jdweng).

Answer (score 0):

Without serializable classes or superfluous code you can do this simply changing GetRoles as follows:

```
    <WebMethod()>
    Public Function GetRoles(ByVal ID As String, ByVal ROLE As String) As String
        Dim log As String = ""
        Dim sqlconn As New SqlConnection
        Dim sqlconn2 As New SqlConnection
        Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand
        'Dim listOfficerRoles As New List(Of String)()
        Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder("")


        Try
            sqlconn2.ConnectionString = STR_CONFIG
            Dim sqlcmd2 = New SqlCommand
            sqlcmd2.Connection = sqlconn2
            sqlconn2.Open()
            Dim sqlquery2 = "select a.LOGIN,a.USER,
                                    STUFF((select ', ' + CAST(ROLE AS  VARCHAR(1000)) from STROLE b where 
                                    b.USER = a.USER
                                    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS ROLES 
                                    from T_USER a where ID = @ID
                                    group by a.ID, a.LOGIN"
            With sqlcmd2
                .Connection = sqlconn2
                .CommandText = sqlquery2
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID)
            End With
            sqlcmd2.CommandText = sqlquery2
            Dim ds = New DataSet()
            Dim sqlreader2 = sqlcmd2.ExecuteReader()
            If sqlreader2 IsNot Nothing And sqlreader2.HasRows Then
                While sqlreader2.Read()

                    'listOfficerRoles.Add(sqlreader2("LOGIN").ToString)
                    'listOfficerRoles.Add(sqlreader2("ID").ToString)
                    'listOfficerRoles.Add(sqlreader2("ROLES").ToString)
                    sb.AppendLine("<RECORDS>")
                    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("<LOGIN>{0}</LOGIN>", sqlreader2("LOGIN").ToString))
                    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("<ID>{0}</ID>", sqlreader2("ID").ToString))
                    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("<ROLES>{0}</ROLES>", sqlreader2("ROLES").ToString))
                    sb.AppendLine("</RECORDS>")
                End While
            End If

            'Return listOfficerRoles
            Return String.Format("<DOCUMENT>{0}</DOCUMENT>", sb.ToString)

    End Function
```

then from client side you can elaborate the String received as Xml.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but i think i need to change my XML type as for now i see its returning all XML in one stament. and type is  : anyType d1p1:type="q1:string"

Comment: My answer was based on your original question. To have a XML content with types you may consider other techniques (like DataTable then you save its content to Xml or other ways).

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot. Happy coding.